# User form won't fully load

Tags: excel, vba

I have a processing user form that doesn't load all the way. The order of processes I currently have is that when I click a button the "PROCESSING" user form opens, then that user form will run another code then close.  I am not sure if this order is what is causing my issue, but the PROCESSING window never fully loads.  Any thoughts?

```
Sub refreshbuttonclick()

    PROCESSING.Show

    End Sub


    Private Sub UserForm_activate()

      Application.Run "'Operation Get Tough Book Tablets.xlsm'!refresh"

    Unload Me

    End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious why you would want to use a userform to just run another macro?  Is there something you would want to display or?

Comment: You do realize that this statement, when encountered at run-time, will close the userform "PROCESSING":  `Unload Me`  Is that what you intend to do?

Comment: This is a user form telling the user that the macro is running and to wait... Like a loading screen, that is why I have it calling another macro to run when it activates.  And yes, I do intend to close the form once the macro is finished running.

Comment: The problem is that the form doesn't load everything before it runs the other macro.  I have tried adding a wait command, that didn't work.  I am looking for a way to force the form to load fully, before running the other macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Wait` command that you tried to add, as you said in one of your comments, would block the thread of execution, effectively making the application look unresponsive/"hung".

What you can do instead is use `OnTime` to *schedule* the operation/macro to start running a little time in the future to hopefully give your user form enough time to fully load. Perhaps try something like this:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "'Operation Get Tough Book Tablets.xlsm'!refresh"
```

This should give the user form a couple of seconds to fully load before the macro starts executing. You can tailor the scheduling delay to your requirements with trial and error.

Comment: This would work if at the end of my macro called refresh I closed the userform... But I couldn't figure out how to do that...Closing a userform inside of a macro that the userform calls to run

Comment: @Pike7893: I'm not sure it matters from where you close your userform. Did you try my suggestion and it gave you some unexpected result? If so, what happened?

Comment: @Pike7893: I don't particularly like this, but one suggestion could be to keep a global boolean variable that can be accessed by both the macro and your `refreshbuttonclick` code and do a "busy wait" loop, like: `Do While Not macro_done DoEvents Loop`. You add that after `PROCESSING.Show` and before exiting the Sub. Once the boolean is set to True by the macro when it has finished, then the code can unload the userform (`Unload PROCESSING`).

Comment: @Pike7893: That's great, well done! I hope you didn't use my "hack" but found a better way to do it.

Comment: That would work as well.. But I fixed the closing issue at the end of the macro... I thought [ Unload () ] required ()... but I was wrong when I ran it with just Unload PROCESSING at the end of the macro, it worked.  Thank you for your help.